# ASP.NET MVC partial view jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with jQuery Datatables plugin in mvc.

I have a view with ajax-form whitch load a partial view with table on sumbit.

View

```
...
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myList" }, new { @id = "searchForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
                                // some html  
    }
    <div id="myList">

    </div>
```

Partial View with table

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>
<table id="productsTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Description)</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "MyController", new {id =            item.Id})">
                    </a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "MyController", new {id = item.Id})" >
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that if I put script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#productsTable').DataTable();
});
```

in main View it will be not work because partial view load by ajax. And if I put this script in partial view it will be work with delay: at first user will see simple html table and than it will be convert to datatable.

Is there any way to correct load partial view with datatable?
Thanks for advices.

Comment: What if you put the `$('#productsTable').DataTable();` outside of `$(document).ready(function(){}`?

Comment: The same problem - it will show simple html table and than convert to datatable

Comment: Try to render your partial view by using @{Html.RenderAction("MyAction", "MyController");}

Comment: How did it go? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything on the server to "preload" the datatable, since it can only be run on the client. To run `DataTable()`, the browser needs to have loaded both jQuery and HTML before you can transform it, which is why there is a "blink" of ugly.

I suggest you load it (with Ajax if you wish) into a div with CSS `position:absolute;` and `visibility:hidden;` (not `display:none;` and position it somewhere off screen (for example with `left: -3000em;` or similar). After everything is loaded and `DataTable()` has run, you can move the div to where it should be with JS and toggle `position` and `visibility` back to normal.

You can even do this with a sweet fade-in effect, if you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#productsTable').DataTable();
});
```

you should place this code inside the success of ajax call.
I think this may solve your problem :)

Comment: adding the $(document).ready(function() {  to my ajax return function didn't work. It still says DataTable is not a function. :(
If I have .DataTable() inside the main $(document).ready() call, and have the html loaded without ajax, it works.